# Android - TCP server Still connected but connection not working

Tags: android, tcp, kiosk-mode

Hey I'm developing a Kiosk application with a Mediatek Android Device. I have a single app running.

The app is running a TCP server waiting for messages. It works perfectly but after a few hours/days, the Internet connection is not working anymore:

- The device still has its IP
- Android thinks the device is still connected
- Cannot ping from the Device or To the Device
- Only solution is to disable WiFi and the start it again.

Do you have an idea why this kind of issue is happening? How can I avoid it? Any idea how I can debug this issue?

Comment: Since can't ping through same TCP connection, then why not to try to drop connection and reestablish it again? TCP though should be able to provide error handling if something is wrong. If I remember right, important to ping/pong tcp connection by some interval to make sure data can be sent both/ways.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I'm developing a connected object and I need the total traffic data to be less than 1 MB/month so I can't ping :(

Comment: If you have custom protocol special packet could be introduced to be something like 4 bytes top (include type PING/PONG and meta info).

If you send it twice a day both ways PING and PONG it is 31*2*4*2 = 496 bytes. You still would have remaining 1024*1024-496=1,048,080 bytes.

Is it not enough?

Comment: I'm afraid not because I need these 1 MB for other purposes + it means that I detect the connection is off after up to 12 hours which is not acceptable. Is it normal behaviour that the connection disconnects without any reason?

Comment: Basically you would need ping each 15 min in normal case if no data sent. Routers will terminate connection once they notice there is no data flow. I might be mistaken, but last time I was working on similar thing, that's what I ended up doing, pinging each 15 min (max limit). One optimization could be, ping 15 min after last packet sent/received. Hope this helps.